# How to search in the antd dropdown and if the entered option is not available then it should add new option?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, antd

How to search in the antd dropdown and if the entered option is not available then it should add new option, it should be only single value selector.I have a dropdown in which i get the options from api, it is a search dropdown , so when i enter the value that don't match with any option, i want to pass that value to the database, how can i achieve this using antd ?